# Globalize2 and migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, migration, globalize2

I have used globalize2 to add i18n to an old site. There is already a lot of content in spanish, however it isn't stored in globalize2 tables. Is there a way to convert this content to globalize2 with a migration in rails?

The problem is I can't access the stored content:

```
>> Panel.first
=> #<Panel id: 1, name: "RT", description: "asd", proje....
>> Panel.first.name
=> nil
>> I18n.locale = nil
=> nil
>> Panel.first.name
=> nil
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you solved this one way or another but here goes. You should be able to use the `read_attribute` method to dig out what you're looking for.

I just used the following to migrate content from the main table into a globalize2 translations table.

1. Add the appropriate `translates` line to your model.
2. Place the following in `config/initializers/globalize2_data_migration.rb`:

   ```
   require 'globalize'
   module Globalize
     module ActiveRecord
       module Migration

         def move_data_to_translation_table
           klass = self.class_name.constantize
           return unless klass.count > 0
           translated_attribute_columns = klass.first.translated_attributes.keys
           klass.all.each do |p|
             attribs = {}
             translated_attribute_columns.each { |c| attribs[c] = p.read_attribute(c) }
             p.update_attributes(attribs)
           end
         end

         def move_data_to_model_table
           # Find all of the translated attributes for all records in the model.
           klass = self.class_name.constantize
           return unless klass.count > 0
           all_translated_attributes = klass.all.collect{|m| m.attributes}
           all_translated_attributes.each do |translated_record|
             # Create a hash containing the translated column names and their values.
             translated_attribute_names.inject(fields_to_update={}) do |f, name|
               f.update({name.to_sym => translated_record[name.to_s]})
             end

             # Now, update the actual model's record with the hash.
             klass.update_all(fields_to_update, {:id => translated_record['id']})
           end
         end
       end
     end
   end
   ```
3. Created a migration with the following:

   ```
   class TranslateAndMigratePages < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def self.up
       Page.create_translation_table!({
         :title => :string,
         :custom_title => :string,
         :meta_keywords => :string,
         :meta_description => :text,
         :browser_title => :string
       })

       say_with_time('Migrating Page data to translation tables') do
         Page.move_data_to_translation_table
       end
     end

     def self.down
       say_with_time('Moving Page translated values into main table') do
         Page.move_data_to_model_table
       end
       Page.drop_translation_table!
     end
   end
   ```

Borrows heavily from Globalize 3 and refinerycms.

Comment: Wow, had forgotten about this, we even stopped using globalize a while ago!